# How do I take manual inputs in Python for a 'for' loop?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I'm trying to take manual inputs and use those inputs inside a *for* loop to spit out results within a CSV file and I can't get it to work.

I tried to make an input variable outside the *for* loop which takes in an int value which doesn't seem to get passed into the *for* loop. I'm also trying to manually enter the amount of memory, and the OS name. The goal is to spit out the server name.

CSV file:

```
Name,CPU,Memory,OS
server1,2,4gb,windows 7
server2,4,2gb,arch linux
server3,8,4gb,ubuntu linux
server4,4,2gb,windows server
server5,2,4gb,windows 7
```

Python code:

```
import csv


entercpu = int (input("Enter number of CPU: "))
#enteros = input("Enter the OS: ")
#entermemory = input("Enter the amount of memory: ")


with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    for d in dict_reader:

        if d['NumCpu'] == 'entercpu' and d['Guest OS'] == 'windows 7' and d['MemoryGB'] == '8':
            print('Name: {Name}, CPU: {NumCpu}, Memory: {MemoryGB}, OS: {Guest OS}'.format(**d))
```

The output should be: Name:

`Name: Server 1, CPU: 4, Memory: 8, OS: windows 7` and
`Name: Server 5, CPU: 4, Memory: 8, OS: windows 7`

Comment: `'entercpu'` will just yield the string literal `"entercpu"`. What you want is probably `str(entercpu)` (Either that or don't convert `entercpu` to `int` at all at the beginning of the script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```py
if d['NumCpu'] == str(entercpu) and d['Guest OS'] == 'windows 7' and d['MemoryGB'] == '8':
            print('Name: {Name}, CPU: {NumCpu}, Memory: {MemoryGB}, OS: {Guest OS}'.format(**d))
```

You need to make sure that your types are the same when you compare them. For example `4 == "4"` returns `False` but `str(4) == "4"` gives `True`

I think when you typed `'entercpu'` that's what you meant to do, but when trying to cast from one type or another you call the constructor (i.e. `str(4)` or `int("4")`).

Hope this helps!

Ash